# How to perform a Restrictions.like on an integer field

Tags: java, database, hibernate, postgresql

I have an integer field in the DB (Postgresql) and my hibernate mapping file that I want to use in a like operation (e.g. `Restrictions.like(Bean.fieldname,'123')`).

The database does not support `like` for integer without explicit type casting `select * from table where text(myint) like '1%'`. Ideally, I'd like to keep the DB field type and Hibernate property type as `integer`s and not have to load all the fields from the DB to iterate through in the Java code.

cheers :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the value really is a *number*, I'd just restrict it to a range - e.g. greater than or equal to 100 and less than 200. I wouldn't have thought you'd really want "all numbers starting with 1" - that suggests that 1 and 10000 are similar, whereas 1 and 2 are totally different. The information in a number should almost always relate to its magnitude, not the digits from its decimal representation.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a LIKE? It's a very strange comparison, that's also why it's not an integer operator.

You could cast the value in the database to text/varchar, but you will kill performance unless you create a special index as well.

Comment: It's a search of product codes which are being stored as integers and need to be searched.

Comment: I see. In all cases I know of, a product code is not a real number, it's a code. In that case you can store the code as a text/varchar and get your LIKE for free. I don't think you have to calculate the `AVG(productcode)` or `productcode + 10`.

Comment: I agree, it's not inherently a number, but the legacy DB has stored it as such possibly for efficiency reasons so it's the situation I'm dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

Restrictions.sqlRestriction("CAST({alias}.myint AS CHAR) like ?", "%1%", Hibernate.STRING));